# Comparing the same value in ioutil package?

Tags: go

I'm puzzled by what this line of code does from the `ioutil` package. It appears to compare the same value twice but casts it twice on one side. Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

```
int64(int(capacity)) == capacity
```

from this function

```
func readAll(r io.Reader, capacity int64) (b []byte, err error) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    // If the buffer overflows, we will get bytes.ErrTooLarge.
    // Return that as an error. Any other panic remains.
    defer func() {
        e := recover()
        if e == nil {
            return
        }
        if panicErr, ok := e.(error); ok && panicErr == bytes.ErrTooLarge {
            err = panicErr
        } else {
            panic(e)
        }
    }()
    if int64(int(capacity)) == capacity {
        buf.Grow(int(capacity))
    }
    _, err = buf.ReadFrom(r)
    return buf.Bytes(), err
}
```

Comment: It's checking for integer overflow.

Comment: A small technical detail: `but casts it twice` -- Go doesn't do type casting, only type conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting `Tim Cooper`'s comment into an answer.

[`bytes.Buffer.Grow`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.Grow) takes in an int and capacity is int64.

> func (b *Buffer) Grow(n int)
>
> Grow grows the buffer's capacity, if necessary, to guarantee space for
>   another n bytes. After Grow(n), at least n bytes can be written to the
>   buffer without another allocation.

As mentioned in GoDoc, Grow is used as an optimisation to prevent further allocations.

`int64(int(capacity)) == capacity`
makes sure that capacity is within the range of int values so that the optimisation can be applied.